# years between two dates in sql server with starting and end date of each of them in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to get years between two dates with their starting and end dates.Suppose if i enter startdate as "07/06/2017" and enddate as "18/09/2019", i want list the years in between with their starting and end date respectively.Kindly suggest me how it can be achieved.

Input Table:

```
BusinessRefId   Period  GoalType                Amount  StartDateUtc    EndDateUtc  Currency
Business B      Year    CommittedTransactionFee 18000   07/06/17 00:00              USD
```

Output Table:

```
BusinessRefId   Period      GoalType                Amount  StartDateUtc    EndDateUtc  Currency
Business B      2019-2020   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   07/06/2019      07/06/2020  USD
Business B      2018-2019   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   07/06/2018      07/06/2019  USD
Business B      2017-2018   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   07/06/2017      07/06/2018  USD
```

I need to split the dates into months i.e. if BusinessGoal.Period = 'Month' and i need a single query that splits the dates according to the Period mentioned in the BusinessGoal table and given in the input and output table for both "Year" and "Month" respectively.
Input Table (BusinessGoal):

```
BusinessRefId   Period  GoalType                Amount  StartDateUtc      EndDateUtc         Currency
Business C      Year    CommittedTransactionFee 18000   05/07/19 00:00:00 19/09/19 00:00:00  USD
```

Output Table (BusinessGoal):

```
BusinessRefId   Period              GoalType                Amount  StartDateUtc         EndDateUtc           Currency
Business C      2019-07 - 2019-08   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   05/07/2019 00:00:00  05/08/2019 00:00:00    USD
Business C      2019-08 - 2019-09   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   05/08/2019 00:00:00  05/09/2019 00:00:00    USD
Business C      2019-09 - 2019-10   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   05/09/2019 00:00:00  05/10/2019 00:00:00    USD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a table of numbers, here i use the simplest one

```
select BusinessRefId 
  , cast(ys.y as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(ys.y + 1 as varchar(4))  Period
  , GoalType, Amount
  , dateadd(year, nmbs.n, tbl.StartDateUtc) StartDateUtc
  , dateadd(year, nmbs.n + 1,tbl.StartDateUtc) EndDateUtc
  , Currency
from 
-- your real table here
(values (1, 'year', 'CommittedTransactionFee', 1800, cast('20160607' as date),  cast (null as date), 'USD')) 
tbl(BusinessRefId, Period, GoalType, Amount, StartDateUtc, EndDateUtc, Currency)
join 
-- table of numbers
(values (0),(1),(2) --,..
 ) nmbs(n)
on dateadd(year, nmbs.n + 1, tbl.StartDateUtc) <= getdate()
cross apply (select Year(tbl.StartDateUtc) + nmbs.n y ) ys
```

**EDIT**

See the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9718d068c39b4c607cf69ef445cccb28)
This is the version of my query with more conditions regarding which rows needed (note differencies in `ON` clause) and how to compute end date. It uses Soundappan's  ddl and  data (extended) which are allegebly satifactory close to the real ddl and  data.
The main idea is the same, use a table of numbers. You may want to have instantiated table in your DB to use it in other similar queries.

Comment: the businessrefid is not integer but a string and also when i insert my real table, the query is returning 0 rows.

Comment: can we modify this query to split the dates for month also.

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi, provide the table ddl and sample data

Comment: can you expain what you are doing in this query?

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi, I'll try, please ask what specifically needs to be explained the query?

Comment: i cannot provide the table ddl and sample data here. Can we do this on mail or some other medium.

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi, you marked Soundappan's answer as accepted.  I conclude ddl and data in this answer is satifactory close to the real problem. I added the fidlle with a version of my query and Soundappan's ddl.

Comment: i have to consider a case where enddate is already provided and not set to NULL

Comment: See the rows 'Business C', 'Business E' in the fiddle. The query contains some conditions fo end date, but I'm not sure what the logic exactly you need. You can play with the fiddle to test different options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199677/discussion-between-shantanu-dwivedi-and-serg).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your query. check below queries it will help.

```
declare @BusinessGoal table  
(BusinessRefId varchar(50),   
Period varchar(50), 
GoalType varchar(100),    
Amount money, 
StartDateUtc datetime,   
EndDateUtc datetime, 
Currency varchar(10))


insert into @BusinessGoal values
('Business A',  'Year',    'CommittedTransactionFee', 45000,   '07/06/19', '00:00',      'USD'),
('Business B',  'Year',   'CommittedTransactionFee', 18000,   '07/06/17', '00:00',      'USD'),
('Business E',  'Year',    'CommittedTransactionFee', 5000 ,   '01/08/2019',  '01/04/2019',  'USD')

declare @tbl_year table 
(yyyy int,
period varchar(50))

insert @tbl_year values
(2015,'2015-2016'),
(2016,'2016-2017'),
(2017,'2017-2018'),
(2018,'2018-2019'),
(2019,'2019-2020'),
(2020,'2020-2021')



select 
a.BusinessRefId,
b.period,
a.GoalType,
a.Amount, 
DATEADD(YY,b.yyyy-YEAR(a.StartDateUtc),a.StartDateUtc) as StartDateUtc,
DATEADD(YY,b.yyyy-YEAR(a.StartDateUtc)+1,a.StartDateUtc) as EndDateUtc ,
a.Currency 
from @BusinessGoal a 
inner join @tbl_year b on b.yyyy  >=year(a.StartDateUtc)
where a.Period='Year' and b.yyyy <=YEAR(GETDATE()) order by a.BusinessRefId,b.period
```

Sample Output

```
BusinessRefId|  period      |   GoalType                |   Amount  |   StartDateUtc|   EndDateUtc  |   Currency
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business A  |   2019-2020   |   CommittedTransactionFee |   45000   |   06/07/2019  |   06/07/2020  |   USD
Business B  |   2017-2018   |   CommittedTransactionFee |   18000   |   06/07/2017  |   06/07/2018  |   USD
Business B  |   2018-2019   |   CommittedTransactionFee |   18000   |   06/07/2018  |   06/07/2019  |   USD
Business B  |   2019-2020   |   CommittedTransactionFee |   18000   |   06/07/2019  |   06/07/2020  |   USD
Business E  |   2019-2020   |   CommittedTransactionFee |   5000    |   08/01/2019  |   08/01/2020  |   USD
```

Comment: can you help me slpitting the dates with respect to BusinessGoal.Period = 'Month' and 'Quarter' too. i can provide you the sample data here or anywhere you prefer.

Comment: Ya ok.. provide sample data and it’s outputs of monthly and quarterly here or mention in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName
WHERE 
convert(DATETIME,tbl_Date)   BETWEEN Convert(DATETIME,CASE WHEN isnull(@FromDate,'')='' THEN jobMain_JobDate ELSE isnull(@FromDate,'') END)                     
AND Convert(DATETIME, CASE WHEN isnull(@ToDate,'')='' THEN tbl_Date ELSE isnull(@ToDate,'') END)
```

You can try this Query...null part is also Handle..

> For E.g. If you are enter only FromDate as "07/06/2017"  then it will
>   give you from result("07/06/2017" to last Date)

Answer (score 1):

you can get years of start and end date and then convert to string and concatenate as below

```
Declare @startdate as date,
 @enddate as date

 set @startdate='09-10-2017'
 set @enddate='07-12-2019'

select convert(varchar,year(@startdate))+'-'+convert(varchar,year(@enddate)) as Period
```

Comment: this splitting is not according the one i mentioned in the question above

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample data and the expected results, you can get it using `DATEADD()` function and `CROSS APPLY` as

```
SELECT BusinessRefId,
       CONCAT(YEAR(DATEADD(Year, -1, SD)), '-', YEAR(SD)) Period,
       GoalType,
       Amount,
       DATEADD(Year, -1, SD) StartDateUtc,
       SD EndDateUtc,
       Currency
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('Business B', 'Year', 'CommittedTransactionFee', 18000, '2017-06-07 00:00:00', NULL, 'USD')
)T(BusinessRefId, Period, GoalType, Amount, StartDateUtc, EndDateUtc, Currency)
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
  (DATEADD(Year, 1, StartDateUtc)),
  (DATEADD(Year, 2, StartDateUtc)),
  (DATEADD(Year, 3, StartDateUtc))
) TT(SD)
ORDER BY SD DESC;
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| BusinessRefId |  Period   |        GoalType         | Amount |    StartDateUtc     |     EndDateUtc      | Currency |
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| Business B    | 2019-2020 | CommittedTransactionFee |  18000 | 07/06/2019 00:00:00 | 07/06/2020 00:00:00 | USD      |
| Business B    | 2018-2019 | CommittedTransactionFee |  18000 | 07/06/2018 00:00:00 | 07/06/2019 00:00:00 | USD      |
| Business B    | 2017-2018 | CommittedTransactionFee |  18000 | 07/06/2017 00:00:00 | 07/06/2018 00:00:00 | USD      |
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f849b1b9ceb8fb20b96ec1e20851f8e2)**</kbd>